# How to add collisions between nodes..?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to add collisions between the node, an instance of one moving node striking violently against another. Because here overlapping one node to another node.i don't know why overlapping between two nodes, because I applied collisions.

Then I am already trying this, this following code are not working, so please tell me without resizing, how to add collisions.

```
function getGraphDataSets () {
  var width = 960,
    height = 500

  function shouldShowLink (link, baseNode) {
    return link.source === baseNode || link.target === baseNode
  }

  let highlightLink = null
  const imgs = ['../AzureIcons/ResourceGroup_COLOR.png', '../AzureIcons/Azure Virtual Machine_COLOR.png', '../AzureIcons/Azure Virtual Network_COLOR.png', '../AzureIcons/NetworkInterface.png', '../AzureIcons/publicIpAdress.png', '../AzureIcons/Network Security Group_COLOR.png', 'all.png', 'all.png', 'all.png', 'all.png', 'all.png']
  const colors = ['#D2691E', '#FF0000', '#FFFF00', '#00FF00', '#00FFFF', '#0000FF', '#808080', '#808000', '#008000', '#008080', '#f0ffff', '#C0C0C0', '#512E5F', '#F4D03F', '#f0ffff']
  const linkLength = [2, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150]
  const NODE_REL_SIZE = 1
  const controls = { 'BackGroundColor': 'aqua' }
  const controls2 = { 'linkColor': 'aqua' }
  var resourceData = []
  // var force = d3.layout.force(); 
  const gui = new dat.GUI()

  gui.add(controls, 'BackGroundColor', ['aqua', 'lightsteelblue', 'lavender', 'snow', 'gainsboro', 'tan', 'gainsboro', 'navajowhite', 'floralwhite', 'lightyellow', 'silver', 'peru', 'rosybrown', 'cornsilk', 'lightslategray', 'slategray', 'seashell', 'azure', 'honeydew', 'aliceblue', 'pink', 'plum', 'mediumpurple', 'powderblue', 'palegreen', 'darkseagreen', 'olive', 'lemonchiffon', 'moccasin'])
    .onChange(orientation => Graph && Graph.backgroundColor(orientation))

  const controls3 = { 'DAG Orientation': 'null'}
  const gui3 = new dat.GUI()
  gui3.add(controls3, 'DAG Orientation', ['lr', 'td', 'zout', 'radialout'])
    .onChange(orientation => Graph && Graph.dagMode(orientation))

  const loadBlocks = function (Graph) {
    // qwest.get('../datasets/sample.json').then((_, data) => {
    qwest.get('../datasets/realData.json').then((_, data) => {


      var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data.nodes)
        .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(5))
        .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
        .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(Math.random() * 25))


      // console.log(data.links)
      // filter ResouceGroup
      data.nodes.forEach(node => {
        node.name = `${node.id ? node.id + ': ' : ''}${node.discription || node.group}`
      })

      const linkForce = Graph
        .d3Force('link')
        .distance(link => link.value)

      Graph
        .linkWidth(2)
        .linkOpacity(0.5)
        .linkColor(link => link.vulnerability ? 'red' : 'grey')
        .nodeAutoColorBy('type')
        .backgroundColor('azure')
        .nodeAutoColorBy('id')
        .dagMode('td')
        .linkLabel(link => `
        <br><span style="background-color: #FFFFFF" class="text-highlighted"><font color="red" size="5">
        ${link.vulnerabilityStatus}
        </font>
        </span>
         `)
        .onLinkClick(link => {
          d3.select('h1').html(link.vulnerabilityStatus)
          d3.select('h2').html(link.vulnerabilityBrief)
        })
        .nodeLabel(node => `
        <br><span style="background-color: #FFE4C4" class="text-highlighted"><font color="black" size="2">
        ${node.id}
        </font>
        </span>
         `)
        .onNodeClick(node => {
          d3.select('h1').html(node.id)
          d3.select('h2').html(node.discription)
        })
        .enableNodeDrag(true)
        .nodeThreeObject(({ type }) => geometryAlgorithem(type))
        .graphData(data)
    })
  }
  // Node Filter
  const filterNode = { 'filterNode': 'Select Resource Filter' }
  const filterNodegui = new dat.GUI()
  filterNodegui.add(filterNode, 'filterNode', ['virtualMachine', 'storageAccount', 'resourceGroup', 'PaaSService', 'Networks', 'reset'])
    .onChange(filterNode => Graph && filterConfiguration(filterNode, Graph))

  return [loadBlocks]
}
```